# Spring 4.0 and annotation configuration

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, annotations

I hava a question about Spring 4.0 (namely 4.0.6 or 4.1.0). I was reading documentation for spring, but it seems that is not updated to version 4 of spring. I was wondering if configuration using annotation only is possible? I read in docs that some features are not possible, and the best solution is to keep xml based configuration and if needed, add  to the container xml config file.

I don't see any profit in having configuration in xml and in java files. If I would have to choose mixed configuration and XML only configuration, I would choose XML only configuration, but if I will have to choose Java based config and XML based config, I would choose java based config. But the question is, are they the same? Do JavaConfig and XML Config have the same possibilities?

Comment: What features are not possible? Give some examples (with links) from the documentation itself.

Comment: For the most part, it's going the other way around (i.e. Java config provides even more flexible callback contracts that allow to tune the config more than what the XML namespace provides). I second Andrei's comment: provide references of what you claim please. Thanks.

Comment: Mixing XML resources and annotated classes
There is "If you use XML configuration in production, you may decide that you want to use Configuration classes to configure specific Spring-managed components for your tests, or vice versa."
And in the section Combining Java and XML configuration There is a sentence:
Spring’s @Configuration class support does not aim to be a 100% complete replacement for Spring XML

So I assume that it doesn't cover all cases. Are those cases important?
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining

Comment: Actually in my project I use java based configuration only. For me there is no way to come back again to XMLs. In my opinion @Configuration is very clean, simple and really nice for debugging.

Comment: Marek I think that you have right, but I just wanted to be sure that java config is at least same as xml based config.